# How can I select the element of HTML by combing both class and id attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have a code like this

```
function openCompare(y)
{
 var z = y.id;
 $(y).hide();
 $(z'.comp1').show();
}
```

when we click on a button then it is called the openCompare() function

var z contains the id of the button which I want to hide

Now I have another button with same id z and class name comp1 which was hidden previously. How can I show this button using their both class and id property?

Comment: Id has to be unique. No two buttons can have same id's

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Possibly simpler ways to approach this issue but no way to know without the html and how you use this

Answer (score 0):

`var a = document.getElementById("YOURID");` - search by ID

`var b = document.getElementsByClassName("YOURCLASS");` - array of DOM elements with class "YOURCLASS"

Better search only by id (var a = ...) because it unique and fast operation document.searchElementById()

You mustn't have 2+ id with same name

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript using css selectors you would use a selector like this: `document.querySelector("#id.class")...` Same for for jquery: `$("#id.class")...`

As highlighted by other users ids should be unique, you should fix that beforehand too.